# Anyone can explain the functionality of In App Review popup

Tags: android

We have Integrated 'In App Review' in our App, but we are facing some trouble after publishing in Play Store.

1. Popup not showing after clicking 'Not Now' button
2. Popup showing based on Device not mail address
3. After submitting the review, If we remove from play store, Popup will
   come or not

Answer (score 0):

The In-App review flow has some restrictions on when the pop-up will be shown.

1. There's an *unknown* limit to the number of times an user can see the review flow pop-up in a short period of time, e.g. 3 times in a month. This limit is undisclosed but nonetheless there is a limit. This is to improve overall user experience so that developers are unable to spam users, asking for a review. So when you call `launchReviewFlow`, it doesn't always result in a pop-up being shown
2. Since an user can have multiple devices, I think pop-up quotas would be enforced per user per device. Of course this is mere speculation since documentation doesn't have any information on the limits of these quotas.
3. Documentation doesn't mention a scenario like this but I think it is safe to assume that the flow will be shown again after the user deletes their review from the Play Store.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

**Edit**: Behaviour assumed in #3 is correct as confirmed by @VasiliyT.

Comment: 3. Personally checked — review dialog will be shown after existing review deleted from the Play Store.